# Which minimum iOS version should my app support if creating BLE app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am about to start new application and my customer want to support iOS 5 and iPhone 5 also including all latest range devices. I am using swift and official apple doc saying it supports till iOS 7.  My app will going to work based on BLE and location update data and basically its a IOT application.Issue is should i start giving support from iOS 7 or 5 or from 9? I do not have any exact clue why I should not choose iOS 7 version and I should start iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by checking the device capability table here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

As it states there, the first device compatible with Bluetooth Low Energy is iPhone 4s.

With that in mind you could possibly support the first iOS version which supports **iPhone 4s**, [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) it is **iOS 5**. As others mentioned Core Bluetooth was introduced a bit later.

Now you should understand that supporting all versions starting from such an old OS version will introduce **A LOT** of work. Then you have 2 questions which we cannot answer:

1. Do you want to do that work?
2. Is your customer willing to pay for it?

As for link for your customer I guess you could use this:

https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_10

I would say that Mixpanel is quite a big company which tracks iOS distribution numbers pretty precise.

Answer (score 1):

The facetious reply - nonetheless a valid one - is to find another client.

A more rational reply is to speak *reasonably* to your client with *confidence* and *knowledge* of history.

- 1 iOS underwent a major UI change with iOS 7, what's to be gained by supporting something older?
- 2 If the device in question is *actually* running iOS 5 today it probably cannot use iOS 8 or above.
- 3 As you said, Swift will not run on a device unless it's iOS 7 and above.
- 4 The *historical* adoption rate for the next version of iOS - since I believe the start of history in 2007 - is well above 80% in the first year and 90% the year after.

Combining these things, you have several arguments for this client. (And yes, this question and/or answer likely belongs in the [freelancing site](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com).)

- 1 Why the need for iOS 5?

Give them the current numbers of how many devices *currently still run* iOS 5. Have *them* defend this reason, or else find another client.

- 2 If the client is "closed", meaning they aren't looking to market your code, then why are they using devices running iOS 5?

Again, the *only* reason to use that old a version - understanding that a device running iOS 5 is old enough *yet* likely new enough to at least run iOS 7 - is that they are cash-strapped. Frankly, that's a client I'd run from. Quick.

- 3 There's two likely reason for this request. (a) They are testing you to see how you reply. (b) They are not as informed as you about the current state of the iOS market.

Let's take the the latter one first. Be informed and knowledgable and stick with the facts. Use the arguments I lined out above. If they aren't convinced - you probably need to drop them as a client. While the "customer rules", nobody wants a client you cannot reason with.

As for the former - the client is testing you?

Again, give them the facts - you *can* support iOS5, but with limitations - later versions of iOS may not run those devices, later *features* introduced in iOS (particularly UI things like auto layout, `UICollectionViews`, etc.) mean extreme complications in the code base... adding *both* time and money, and it needs to be written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5?! Right now iOS 9 has 92% of active devices so you should definitely choose it or even iOS 10.

For BLE as you mentioned iOS 7 and iPhone 4S is minimum.

Comment: Yes , I know but I do not have any official link where apple recommend latest. I can not show my client on this number basis only. And even I did not find any strong reason to deny this. I want to support from iOS 9 /10 but no valide reason to do so. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) that Core Bluetooth was introduced in iOS 5, so you can target that version and still have BLE support but only in Objective-C

However, there will be a number of other enhancements in iOS that you will not be able to take advantage of and this will make development more difficult Andre therefore more expensive.

iOS 5 is very old and probably represents a very small percentage of devices.